# Multivariate Normal pdf in Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Trying to evaluate scipy's `multivariate_normal.pdf` function, but keep getting errors.  MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvnorm

x = np.random.rand(5)
mvnorm.pdf(x)
```

gives

```
TypeError: pdf() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
```

The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) say both the `mean` and `cov` arguments are optional, and that the last axis of `x` labels the components.  Since `x.shape` = `(4L,)`, it seems like all is kosher.  I am expecting a single number as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It looks like these parameters aren't optional.***

If I pass the default values for `mean` and `cov` like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvnorm

x = np.random.rand(5)
mvnorm.pdf(x, mean=0, cov=1)
```

I get the following output:

```
array([ 0.35082878,  0.27012396,  0.26986049,  0.39887847,  0.36116341])
```

---

While using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvnorm

x = np.random.rand(5)
mvnorm.pdf(x)
```

gives me the same error:

```
TypeError: pdf() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Even when you specify the `mean` and `cov` arguments, why doesn't the function return a single number, that being the multivariate normal pdf evaluated at `x`

Comment: @bcf Apparently the function infers the dimension from the shapes of `mean` and/or `cov`.  If `x` has length 5 and it is meant to be a single point in 5d, try `mvnorm.pdf(x, mean=np.zeros(5), cov=1)`.

Comment: *"It looks like these parameters aren't optional."*  Bug report created here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6263